# Generating an NSMutableDictionary with objects of different format

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

How could I generate an `NSMutableDictionary` of the following format:

```
{
sitedetails = {
    currency;
    ere =         {
        price =             {
            test =                 {
                              gte = 100;
                                   };
                           };
                   };
               };
}
```

`sitedetails` is the key and currency (`NSString`) and `ere`(`NSMutableDictionary` with its own objects) are the objects of this `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = ;[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict1 setObject:@"currency" forKey:@"sitedetails"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = ;[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict2 setObject:ereDict forKey:@"sitedetails"];
[dict1 addEntriesFromDictionary:dict2];
```

This didn't let me add the string value in for `dict1`. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
 {
sitedetails =  {
    ere =        {
        price =     {
            test =    {
                gte = 100;
                      };
                    };
                  };
               };
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because dict1 and dict2 have the key 'sitedetails'. Keys **should** be unique in a dictionary.
From [NSMutableDictionary reference manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsmutabledictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_6)

> If both dictionaries contain the same key, the receiving dictionary’s
>   previous value object for that key is sent a release message, and the
>   new value object takes its place.

Comment: if dict2 has a dummy key and how do i add it to dict1 such that it has two objects (a string and dictionary)

Comment: It seems like you need one more level in the dictionary. It doesn't seem to make much sense that a _key_ of 'sitedetails' has a _value_ of  'currency'.

Comment: Using the NSMutableDictionary you unfortunately **cannot** have a _dummy_ key. Consider another data structure if having non-unique keys is necessary.